# apply style to div with a class when hovering an element with an id

Tags: css

I have this:

```
#ribbon:hover {
height: 135px;
overflow-x: auto;
}
```

and I want to apply a top to a div with a class `menu-offset` when the `#ribbon` is hover

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
#ribbon:hover.menu-offset {
   top: 135px;
}
```

Comment: #ribbon:hover .menu-offset {
   top: 135px;
}